# 404 error when trying to access my GitHub page

Tags: github, github-pages

It shows 404 when I try to access my GitHub page.  What am I doing wrong?

*My GitHub page:* https://krislu.github.io/

*My GitHub repo:* https://github.com/KrisXDLu/

Answer (score 1):

From [GitHub Pages instructions](https://pages.github.com/):

> Head over to GitHub and create a new repository named username.github.io, where username is your username (or organization name) on GitHub.
>
> If the first part of the repository doesn’t exactly match your username, it won’t work, so make sure to get it right.

You didn't get it right. "KrisXDLu" ≠ "KrisLu"